# CRUD with Python ... IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, crud

I have to do a couple of selects and an update using Python.  Totally new at this language, and I am having a bit of trouble with the syntax when doing the following (simple) queries:

```
SELECT A.CUSTOMER_NAME,
A.CUSTOMER_CITY,
B.POPULATION
FROM
CONTRACTS AS A
JOIN CITIES AS B ON
A.CUSTOMER_CITY = B.IDENT
WHERE B.POPULATION <=500000

SELECT A.IDENT,
A.MAKE,
A.MODEL,
A.LUXURY,
B.CAR_IDENT
FROM CARS AS A
JOIN CONTRACTS AS B ON
A.IDENT = B.CAR_IDENT
WHERE LUXURY = 'Y'

UPDATE CONTRACTS
SET BASE_PRICE=1000
WHERE CONTRACT_CLASS >=10
```

I am starting with the update...i figured it was shorter to code....
    When I do the update statement, I get the following error:

```
>'update {} set BASE_PRICE = ? where {}'.format(self._table), (row['BASE_PRICE'], >row['where']))
>IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Here's what I have for my methods

```
    def retrieve(self, key):
        cursor = self._db.execute('select  from {}'.format(self._table))
        return dict(cursor.fetchone())

    def update(self, row):
        self._db.execute(
            'update {} set BASE_PRICE = ? where {}'.format(self._table), 
            (row['BASE_PRICE'], row['where']))
        self._db.commit()

    def disp_rows(self):
        cursor = self._db.execute('select IDENT, CONTRACT_CLASS, BASE_PRICE from {} order 
        by BASE_PRICE'.format(self._table))
        for row in cursor:
            print('  {}: {}: {}'.format(row['IDENT'], row['CONTRACT_CLASS'], 
            row['BASE_PRICE']))

    def __iter__(self):
        cursor = self._db.execute('select * from {} order by  
        BASE_PRICE'.format(self._table))
        for row in cursor:
            yield dict(row)


    def main():
    db_cities = database(filename = 'insurance.sqlite', table = 'CITIES')
    db= database(filename = 'insurance.sqlite', table = 'CONTRACTS')
    db_cars = database(filename = 'insurance.sqlite', table = 'CARS')

    print('Retrieve rows')
    for row in db: print(row)

    print('Update rows')
    db.update({'where': 'CONTRACT_CLASS' >= 10', 'BASE_PRICE'= 1000})
    for row in db: print(row)

    print('Retrieve rows after update')
    for row in db: print(row)

Thanks in advance for your help!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced a bracket after `self._table`.

```py
'UPDATE {table_name} SET BASE_PRICE = {base_price} WHERE {condition}'.format(
     table_name=self._table,
     base_price=row['BASE_PRICE'],
     condition=row['where']
 )
```

I also did a little code cleanup.

Another question: Why aren't you using an ORM?

Comment: Did you now understand the usage of `format()`? The fact I'm using names in the braces is more idomatically, without them also works but isn't that readable.

Comment: how about when I have to do SQL joins....how to reference more than 1 table in the db.execute?  def retrieve(self, key):
        cursor = self._db.execute('select * from {}'.format(self._table))
        return dict(cursor.fetchone())

Comment: 'def retrieveSmCityCust(self, key):
        cursor = self._db.execute('SELECT CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER_NAME, CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER.CITY, CITIES.POPULATION FROM CONTRACTS JOIN CITIES ON CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER_CITY = CITIES.IDENT where {condition} '
                                  .format(self_table), condition = row['where'])
        return dict(cursor.fetchall())' throws error     .format(self_table), condition = row['where'])
NameError: global name 'self_table' is not defined

Comment: ORM = Object-relational mapper; Means that you don't need to write plain SQL more. Take a look at [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/) only for example.

In the code above you forget the dot after `self` (it should be `self._table`). You also misplaced the bracket after `self._table` again.

Your mistakes aren't all really python specific. You have to take care by setting brackets, braces, dotts, etc.